# ¿Cómo extraer datos entre dos años?

Tags: sql

Cómo puedo extraer datos entre dos años de 2 tablas
Les dejo el código:

```
SELECT vendedor.Nombre, venta.NroVenta, venta.Fecha 
FROM vendedor INNER JOIN venta 
WHERE venta.Fecha BETWEEN YEAR(venta.Fecha) = 2016 YEAR(venta.Fecha) = 2017
```

Comment: que gestor de bd utilizas?

Comment: phpmyadmin todos me sirven excepto ese no se como incorporarlo para mostrarme las ventas entre esos 2 años

Comment: BETWEEN fechaInicio AND fechaFIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo primero es que estas haciendo un `INNER JOIN` sin especificar la condición del mismo, lo segundo es que te falta `AND` en el `BETWEEN`. Sin que me muestres las tablas creo que lo que quieres lograr es algo como esto:

```
 SELECT vendedor.Nombre, venta.NroVenta, venta.Fecha FROM venta
 INNER JOIN vendedor ON venta.RutVen = vendedor.RutVen
 WHERE YEAR(venta.Fecha) BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017
```

Las combinaciones internas se realizan mediante la instrucción `INNER JOIN`. **Devuelven únicamente aquellos registros/filas que tienen valores idénticos en los dos campos que se comparan para unir ambas tablas**. Es decir aquellas que tienen elementos en las dos tablas, identificados éstos por el campo de relación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: acabo de probarlo pero aun así me da error... no se que mas puedo hacerle...

Comment: Revisa tenia un error en mi `INNER JOIN` ya lo corregí. Si igual te falla por favor dime el error. Puedes mostrar las estructuras de tus 2 tablas en tu pregunta?.

Comment: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '= 2016 AND YEAR(venta.Fecha) = 2017 LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 3 (ME MARCA ESE ERROR)

Comment: Ya lo vi es un error en el `BETWEEN` vuelve a probar.

Comment: SELECT vendedor.Nombre, venta.NroVenta, venta.Fecha FROM venta INNER JOIN vendedor ON venta.RutVen = vendedor.RutVen WHERE venta.Fecha BETWEEN 2016 AND 2017 (así era, muchas gracias)

Comment: Listo, valida la respuesta como buena para que lo puedan usar otras personas con tu misma duda.